# Gulp, Wiredep and Bower dependencies

Tags: node.js, gulp, bower, wiredep

I want to adapt a gulpfile.js and change my `bower_components/` folder to `app/bower_components/`.

I updated the directory in `.bowerrc`, so now everytime i do a `bower install` it will use the right one:

```
{
  "directory": "app/bower_components"
}
```

**Now, how can `gulp-wiredep` write the correct Sass path location inside my main Sass file?**

For example, `gulp-wiredep` adds the following line in my `main.scss` file, right after `// bower:scss`:

`@import "bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";`

It should be now `@import "app/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";`

How can I change that path? I believe it's some configuration on the `wiredep` task:

```
gulp.task('wiredep', function () {
  var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;

  gulp.src('app/styles/*.scss')
    .pipe(wiredep({
      ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)+/
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/styles'));

  gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(wiredep({
      exclude: ['bootstrap-sass-official'],
      ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)*\.\./
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
});
```

But I don't know how can I configure that to do what I need, I couldn't find any documentation about that.

I know that if I change manually that path in my sass file to `"app/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss"`, the `gulp serve` will work, but as soon as i install a bower component it will change that path to the one without the `app/` at the beginning again and it will break the task.

How to fix that?

Done:

```
// inject bower components
gulp.task('wiredep', function () {
  var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;

  gulp.src('app/styles/*.scss')
    .pipe(wiredep({

      fileTypes: {
        scss: {
          replace: {
            sass: '@import "app/{{filePath}}";',
            scss: '@import "app/{{filePath}}";'
          }
        }
      },

      ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)+/
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/styles'));

  gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(wiredep({
      exclude: ['bootstrap-sass-official'],
      ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)*\.\./
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `directory` option of wiredep:

```
  gulp.src('app/styles/*.scss')
    .pipe(wiredep({
      directory: 'app/bower_components',
      fileTypes: {
        scss: {
          replace: {
            scss: '@import "src/app/{{filePath}}";'
          }
        }
      },
      ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)+/
    }));

gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(wiredep({
      directory: 'app/bower_components',
      exclude: ['bootstrap-sass-official'],
      ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)*\.\./
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
```

Also, see [their documentation](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep#configuration)

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. It says in the documentation it uses the default '.bowerrc' directory, so that would be unnecessary anyway, right?

Comment: I also tried changing `cwd`, but apparently that's where wiredep will search for `bower.json`

Comment: It seems to work for me, though you have to add the directory option to the task where you stream `app/styles/*.scss`, not to the html one as shown in my answer.  If you delete the old bower_components folder and wiredep still searches there, then the task should fail with wiredep complaining that it can't find any dependencies. Anyway, you can use the replace override, but you have to specify it differently. See mu update the this answer.

Comment: yes, i know that, the problem is that I had forgotten to wrap in `fileTypes` ! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead wiredep you can use bindep (for installation type npm bindep or https://github.com/publicocean0/bindep). It permits  to create complex projects with optional submodules , resources mapping, file conversions(for example less files) and custom preprocessing.
In html you can specify what submodules inside a single bower component you want,you can filter files,preprocess files passing your paramters...
In the configuration you can set where you want put every type of resource,templates,converters,local dependencies,....